Set Values from Environment variables for appsettings.json in .NetCore application
Usually in spring boot application I set to read the connection string or any similar value from environment variable as below. At the time of application startup, the values will be set and application can read if from application.properties file.
spring.datasource.url=${DB_URL}

Do we have similar option achieve the same in appsettings.json file in .Net Core application? When I start the application, the DB connection and log level to set from the values available in environment variables.
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {    
    "UATDB": "Server=localhost;Database=UAT;User ID={user id};Password={password};Trusted_Connection=false;TrustServerCertificate=True;Integrated Security=False;"    
  }


Hi @Mohamed, there has some sensitive information in your post that may pose a risk to security, so I have already edited your post and hope you can hide the sensitive information in the next time.

Hi @ZhiLv, that was a dummy credentials. However your points is noted with thanks.

Yes, you can set the environment keys and values on Windows, then they will override values read from appsettings.json, appsettings.{Environment}.json, and user secrets.
sample "MyKey":
{
  "MyKey": "My appsettings.json Value",
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}

set commands:
set MyKey="My key from Environment"
dotnet run

The following setx commands can be used to set the environment keys and values on Windows. Unlike set, setx settings are persisted. /M sets the variable in the system environment. If the /M switch isn't used, a user environment variable is set.
setx MyKey "My key from setx Environment" /M

If MyKey is not explicitly defined in the appsettings.json file.
You can use Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable to retrieve the value of MyKey:
string myKey = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("MyKey");

Or using IConfiguration Interface:
public class MyClass
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

    public MyClass(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
    }

    public void MyMethod()
    {
        string myKey = _configuration["MyKey"];
        
    }
}

refer to this document:

Using the default configuration, the
EnvironmentVariablesConfigurationProvider loads configuration from
environment variable key-value pairs after reading appsettings.json,
appsettings.{Environment}.json, and user secrets. Therefore, key
values read from the environment override values read from
appsettings.json, appsettings.{Environment}.json, and user secrets.

